# consulta sql while con if

Tags: sql

tengo un problema en mi consulta, no se como aplicar un WHILE con IF. Tengo 2 tablas, una se llama detalle la segunda subdetalle y tengo que aplicar un while que para registrar los datos de las tablas detalle y subdetalle, si el detalle tiene subdetalle hacer un select y guardar las 2 tablas en una tabla temporal. si no tiene subdetalle solo hacer el seleccionar al detalle y seguir con la otra, estas son las tablas.

```
  declare @tempo table  (
    DETA_Codigo bigint        ,
    NOMN_Codigo bigint  ,
    CONV_Codigo bigint        ,
    DETA_RutBnf int           ,
    DETA_RutDv  char(1)       ,
    DETA_Nombre varchar(70)   ,
    FPAG_Codigo varchar(10)   ,
    DETA_Email  varchar(80)   ,
    DETA_MntPag numeric(19, 4),
    DETA_FecPag datetime       
    )
    INSERT INTO @tempo select TOP 1000
    DETA_Codigo,
    NOMN_Codigo  ,
    CONV_Codigo  ,
    DETA_RutBnf  ,
    DETA_RutDv   ,
    DETA_Nombre  ,
    FPAG_Codigo  ,
    DETA_Email   ,
    DETA_MntPag  ,
    DETA_FecPag 
    from  MPMT_BECH_PROV..DETA 

    Select CONCAT( '2' , '¬' , '¬' , SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,CONV_Codigo),1,100) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,DETA_RutBnf),1,50) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,DETA_RutDv),1,1) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(DETA_Nombre,1,250) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,FPAG_Codigo),1,10) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(DETA_Email,1,80) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,DETA_MntPag),1,50) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,DETA_FecPag,105),1,50)  ) from @tempo

// subdetalle



declare @tempo table  (
  SUBD_Codigo   bigint             ,
 DETA_Codigo    bigint             ,
 NOMN_Codigo    bigint             ,
 CONV_Codigo    bigint             ,
 SUBD_NroDoc    varchar(20)        ,
 SUBD_TipoDoc   varchar(10)        ,
 SUBD_FecDoc    datetime           ,
 SUBD_MontoDoc  numeric(19, 0)  ,
 SUBD_GlosaDoc  varchar(255)    

    )
INSERT INTO @tempo SELECT TOP 1000
 SUBD_Codigo  ,
DETA_Codigo   ,
NOMN_Codigo   ,
CONV_Codigo   ,
SUBD_NroDoc   ,
SUBD_TipoDoc  ,
SUBD_FecDoc   ,
SUBD_MontoDoc ,
SUBD_GlosaDoc
FROM MPMT_BECH_PROV..SUBD
select CONCAT( '2' , '¬' , SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,SUBD_Codigo),1,50) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,DETA_Codigo),1,50) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,NOMN_Codigo),1,50) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,CONV_Codigo),1,50) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(SUBD_NroDoc,1,20) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(SUBD_TipoDoc,1,10) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,SUBD_FecDoc,105),1,50) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,SUBD_MontoDoc),1,50) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(SUBD_GlosaDoc,1,1000) , '¬' , SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,''),1,20) ) from @tempo
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias mostrar que intentaste, los datos y cual queres que sea la salida?

Comment: No necesitas ni WHILE ni IF, todo se hace en 2 pasos usando WHERE.